# What is an accessible way to mark up buttons whose only content is an icon?

Tags: accessibility, title, wai-aria

The design I am implementing has a generic "Account" button whose only content is a user icon (and a tiny dropdown icon).

Is it enough to add a title attribute to the button ("Your account"), or should I add text inside the button that I simply hide visually (while keeping accessible to screen readers), or both?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- If you are using an [`input` image button](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/forms.html#image-button-state-%28type=image%29), use its [`alt` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/forms.html#attr-input-alt):

  ```html
  <input type="image" src="account-icon.png" alt="Your account">
  ```
- If you are using a [`button`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/forms.html#the-button-element) with [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element), use `img`’s [`alt` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/embedded-content-0.html#attr-img-alt):

  ```html
  <button type="button"><img src="account-icon.png" alt="Your account"></button>
  ```
- If you are using an [`a`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) with `img`, use `img`’s `alt` attribute:

  ```html
  <a href="/account.html"><img src="account-icon.png" alt="Your account"></a>
  ```
- If you are adding the icon via CSS (instead of HTML), you should include a text label in the HTML and visually hide it with CSS.

For usability, you might consider using both, an icon and text. But this might be discussed at [User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). See, for example, the question "[When to use icons vs. icons with text vs. just text links?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/1795/17023)".

For deciding which `alt` text to use, see [my answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/48817/17023) to the question "[What should the ALT text be for an image that is also a link?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/48754/17023)". You [should not use the `title` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19776398/1591669) for specifying the alternative text.

Comment: I am using an icon font for the icon (`<button><span class="icon user"></span></button>`). I suppose this doesn't qualify as an image and I should just add a visually hidden label?

Comment: @Elise: Yes, correct. Then this button will also make sense for users without CSS support (text browsers), or screen reader users.

Comment: would it make sense to use aria label on the button or link instead of the alt on the image (keep an empty alt) ? would it be any different ?

Answer (score 3):

So if it's an icon button I have an example on CodePen: [A super accessible button with tooltip](http://codepen.io/DanielGoransson/pen/flewB)

This is the markup I use:

```
<button type="button" class="button"> 
  <span class="button-icon" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#x78;"></span>
  <span class="button-text"><strong>Navigation menu</strong></span>
</button>
```

You can hide the text content with css and make it visible on hover/focus. See example for more deatail on CSS.

Here is a list of what this method  accomplish accessibility wise:

- Is a native `<button>` and therefor inherits:

  - Mouse & keyboard (enter & space) clickability
  - Keyboard foucusability
  - Announciation as a button for screen readers
- CSS injects icon, for non-visual web browsers
- Hides icon for screen readers
- Uses hidden text, for screen readers
- Hides text by z-index -1 insead of off-screen to make it tapable with iOS using VoiceOver screen reader
- Shows text as tooltip on hover and focus
- Tooltip won't disappear on mouse over or slightly outside. This makes the text readable with full zoom.

Answer (score 2):

Use `aria-label` for this. Example:

```html
<button aria-label="Close" onclick="myDialog.close()">X</button>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute):

> The aria-label attribute is used to define a string that labels the current element. Use it in cases where a text label is not visible on the screen. If there is visible text labeling the element, use aria-labelledby instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a button text and hide id visually, or you can add an `alt` attribute to your icon (if it's an `img`). The latter is even better, on my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The following article provides information on using ARIA to enhance SVG accessibility: [Using ARIA to enhance SVG accessibility](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/12/using-aria-enhance-svg-accessibility/). It's dated 2013 and contains several compatibility charts as well as the following code snippet, which had the best accessibility:

```
<svg xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg role="img" aria-labelledby="title desc">
  <title id="title">Circle</title>
  <desc id="desc">Large red circle with a black border</desc>
  <circle role="presentation" cy="60" r="55" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Put that inside a `button` and you should enjoy wide support. Of course, now that SVG2.0 has landed the [ARIA usage](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#WAIARIAAttributes) may change slightly.

If using CSS [`::after`](https://devdocs.io/css/::after) to place your icon your button will probably look something like this:

```
<button></button>
```

In which case you could do this and skip ARIA entirely:

```
<button>the label</button>
```

Otherwise the following should do the trick:

```
<button aria-label="the label"></button>
```

And here's the [SVG Accessibility API Mappings](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-aam-1.0/) (draft as of Jan 2019) which maps how SVGs should work in conjunction with accessibility APIs if you want to get more technical.

Though if you just stick a [`title`](https://devdocs.io/svg/element/title) inside the SVG it will likely work now simply because it's obvious.