# Semantic menu with only images

Tags: css, html, seo, semantic-markup

I am trying to make a menu with images only. Can anyone tell me how I should markup this in the **most semantic way possible**? My best guess would be like this:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu" alt="homepage" id="home"></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.menu {width: 40px; height: 40px}
#home {background: url('...')
```

EDIT: The query is because Ineed to use empty `<a>` tags or alternatively I can put the `<img>` tag within the `<a>` tags.

Comment: can you please make a DEMO?

Comment: Give your anchor text a title attribute with the text of the link for SEO purposes.  Lose the "alt" attribute.

Comment: better you should use `background image` in this case.

Comment: <img> tag has src attribute: correction needed. Rgds,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First, if you are willing to respect HTML5 semantics, your menu should be wraped in a `<nav>` tag.
2. Second, the `alt=""` should be replaced by a `title=""` attribute on the `<a>` tag ([MDN for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a))
3. Third, you should use the `<img>` tag with the `alt=""` attribute so you can add more semantic context.

Your menu could look like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" title=""><img src="" alt="" /></a></li>
        ... OTHER LINKS ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: In such a case, the [`alt` content needs to convey the purpose of the link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19776398/1591669) (and not the description of the `img`!). So the `title` attribute is (usually) not needed here, and it should especially not contain the same information like the `alt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Font-Awesome icons instead of images.

They are light and easy to load while image taking time to load and you can apply CSS on those icon same as text.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

for e.g.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

But for using font-awsome icons you have to include font-awsome CSS and fonts to your directory.

Comment: more example for font-awsome :
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/