# Google shows alt-text as website title

Tags: seo, typo3, google-search

I am trying to optimize a web site which is managed by typo3. There is a page on this website, let's call it *seminars*. When I ask google to search for this Website by entering "Big Company seminars", I receive a result which looks like that:

> **Logo** Seminars - Big company
>   url://seminars.bigcompany.de

The string "Logo" should not be displayed there. So I checked the source code and found that:

```
<title>Seminars - Big Company</title>
```

and

```
<a href="/start"><img src="BigCompanyLogo.png" alt="Logo Seminars"></a>
```

It looks like Google takes the alternative text of this image and uses it as the title for their search results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Surely if it was using the alt text, it wouldn't have " - Big Company" at the end. Seems more of a coincidence to me. Would debug more but we have no code nor example to look through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Search [may change webpage titles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21493507/1591669) they show on their result page. You can’t control this.

About your `alt` content:
Is the page about "Logo Seminars", or does "Logo" mean that the image is the logo? In the latter case, you might want to [remove "Logo" from the `alt` content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#logos,-insignia,-flags,-or-emblems) (or place it, for example, in square brackets). Note that, if the image is the only content of the link, [the `alt` content should describe the link target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19776398/1591669), not the image.